# In ConstraintLayout, what is the meaning of android:layout_width="0dp", when there is no `weight` attribute?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-layout-weight

I have this layout:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlayGoogleMaterialIcons">

  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="0dp">

...
```

What is the meaning of `android:layout_width="0dp"` not in the child of 
`LinearLayout`?

What is the meaning of `android:layout_width="0dp"` when there is no `weight` attribute?

Comment: do u mean to ask why do we need `layout_width="0dp"` when assigning `layout_weight`? could u elaborate?

Comment: what is the meaning of android:layout_width="0dp" when there is not `weight` attribute?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for the children of `ConstraintLayout` if you have set constraints then the `0dp` is for `match_constraint` (take full width, or full height)

> Using 0dp, which is the equivalent of "MATCH_CONSTRAINT"
>   https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout

example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:text="text1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/tv_3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_1"
        tools:text="text2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/tv_2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_1"
        tools:text="text3" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

in the above code (and image) you see that `text1` `TextView` width is the width it needs to write the text `text1`

for text2 and text3 `TextView` it takes the whole width divided by 2 that is what the constraints say

Comment: same as `"wrap_content"`? do you have a doc saying that?

Comment: it isn't the same as `wrap_content`

Comment: what's the difference?

Comment: `wrap_content` will calculate how much the child will need to take. but `match_constraint`(0dp) will take the constraint space.

Comment: i meant to ask `match_parent' == `match_constraint` ?

Comment: 0dp for width, with constraints for start/end to be set as parent then you have the match_parent width, but as it says in the link i have gave you isn't the best way to use the `match_parent` for `constraintLayout`